# GITLAB SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git, gitlab, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to push my first project in gitLab  but i get this error "***fatal: unable to access 'https://.git. : SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate***"

Comment: `https://.git.` seems like an invalid path. Please show us what the remote URL is and how you're trying to push it.

Comment: hi @Magnus Eriksson, due to the privacy policies I cannot put the name of the company, the only that you should know is that the url could be `https://git.companyName.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally i find the solution here
https://newbedev.com/invalid-ssl-certificate-when-pushing-to-git-server

After reading and making the settings, you should do

> `git config --system http.sslCAInfo "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"`

and in the root of your project that you are uploading to gitLab you should do

> `git config http.sslCAInfo "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"`

Comment: That link doesn't seem to be working. Could you please specify what settings were you refering to?

Comment: Downloading crt bundle and using the second command worked for me. I was trying to upload an unrelated repo into a blank personal gitlab instance.

Comment: That solution is good for errors when pushing from a local computer, not GitLab pipeline failure.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue and our dev team recommended running below command :

**git config --global http.sslbackend schannel**

In visual studio, select git , then again select open in command prompt , see below attachment :

[image]

paste the command as suggested above , after that you should be able to perform whatever you were trying to do on git

Answer (score 1):

I have a privately deployed Gitlab runner in a Docker container on my AWS EC2 server, and to solve this problem, I just restarted the Gitlab runner container ✅

Comment: Thank's a lot! I was already planning to make a custom image of node :)