# Git: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git, ssl

I use git, with GitLab, all worked fine, until several days ago I started to get the SSL certificate problem error:

```
PS C:\proj> git clone https://git.company.com/dev/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.company.com/dev/myproject.git/': 
       SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

As I understood, deactivate the SSL verification is a security problem, so I would **not** like the solution where setting `http.sslverify false`.

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68283940/961631). The found solution is to set
`http.sslCAInfo` to `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`", solution that didn't work for me.

Could someone explain in simple words:

- what is that .crt certificate (I suppose it is for the secure handshake between local and distant git servers?),
- how to correctly obtain that certificate
- where to keep it on the dev machine
- how to configure git to use it
- what is the difference between SSH and SSL in this case.

PS. Following the VonC answer I get the proposed version output

[image]

Comment: The path for me is: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt. Hope it helps others

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the [certificate chain](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/what-are-root-certificates-and-intermediate-certificates/) (intermediate and root CA) for your company site.

In a git bash session, as [in here](https://serverfault.com/a/1113992/783):

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect git.company.com:443 -servername git.company.com -showcerts | openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl | openssl pkcs7 -noout -print_certs
```

From there, you need

- save those in a `file.crt`
- reference that file in your global git config

That is:

```
git config --global http."https://*.comany.com/".sslcainfo "C:\path\to\file.crt"
```

Comment: please see the updated OP, I added a capture with the output

Comment: @Putin-TheHero A self-signed certificate then. Try and [get said certificate directly through Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726189/6309).